# GitLab 500: We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: gitlab

Getting the following error when trying to view a .java (and some other) file in GitLab:

## 500: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

***/home/git/gitlab/log/production.log:***

```
Started GET "/xbjoernx/Project1/blob/master/src/de/xbjoernx/project1/NotificationRedirect.java" for  at 2013-07-02 12:00:44 +0200
Processing by BlobController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"xbjoernx/Project1", "id"=>"master/src/de/xbjoernx/project1/NotificationRedirect.java"}
  Rendered shared/_ref_switcher.html.haml (2.2ms)
  Rendered blob/_actions.html.haml (457.1ms)
  Rendered blob/_text.html.haml (482.3ms)
  Rendered blob/_blob.html.haml (972.0ms)
  Rendered blob/show.html.haml within layouts/project_resource (990.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1020ms

ActionView::Template::Error (EPIPE):
    9:   .file_content.code
    10:     - unless blob.empty?
    11:       %div{class: user_color_scheme_class}
    12:         = raw blob.colorize(formatter: :gitlab)
    13:     - else
    14:       %p.nothing_here_message Empty file
  app/views/blob/_text.html.haml:12:in `_app_views_blob__text_html_haml__85795113__642493118'
  app/views/blob/_blob.html.haml:28:in `_app_views_blob__blob_html_haml__678936362__642626818'
  app/views/blob/show.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_blob_show_html_haml___279560956__642657458'
```

Comment: It's a bug! https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1774

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be linked to the [python you are using](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1774#issuecomment-11018534):

> The last 3 issues with an exception on the blob.colorize line were fixed by reinstalling/updating python or making sure `/usr/bin/env` python was >= 2.5 and < 3.0. The next version will contain a check for that.

Also illustrated in [issue 2177](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/2177):

```
dzaporozhets:~/projects/ 
→ python -V
Python 2.7.2+

dzaporozhets:~/projects/ 
→ python2 -V
No command 'python2' found, did you mean:
```

[Issue 2214](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2214#issuecomment-11137058) adds:

> It's an issue, because Python is in transition between 2.x and 3.
>   The problem is, some distros already ship (or are about to ship Python3 as default) so relying on python to be 2.x is treacherous. So I think switching to python2 was right, because this can be fixed to work in all cases.

#### Instructions to fix Python when necessary:

```
# Install Python
sudo apt-get install python

# Make sure that Python is 2.x (3.x is not supported at the moment)
python --version

# If it's Python 3 you might need to install Python 2 separately
sudo apt-get install python2.7

# Make sure you can access Python via `python2`
python2 --version
# If you get a "command not found" error create a link to the python binary
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2
```

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2

works! THX